# Error when running gpg.exe from c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, gnupg

Hi I'm trying to encrypt the zip using the GPG im able to do that from a command line. When i integrated that in a C# application it worked well. But when i integrated it with a Windows service i got Error as **gpg2.exe closed**

Following are the exception details

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: gpg2.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4fa14f63
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_e51a
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: e51a
  Additional Information 2: 4c0d4d78887f76d971d5d00f1f20a433
  Additional Information 3: e51a
  Additional Information 4: 4c0d4d78887f76d971d5d00f1f20a433
```

Following is the code i'm using to encrypt

public bool Encrypt(string inRecipient, string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
{

```
/// File info
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(sourceFile);

ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
s.CreateNoWindow = true;
s.UseShellExecute = false;
s.RedirectStandardInput = true;
s.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
s.RedirectStandardError = true;
s.WorkingDirectory = new FileInfo(pgpPath).DirectoryName;

bool processExited = false;

using (Process p = Process.Start(s))
{

    string recipient = " --recipient \"" + inRecipient + "\"";
    string output = " --output \"" + destinationFile + "\"";
    string encrypt = " --encrypt \"" + sourceFile + "\"";
    string homedir = " --homedir \"" + HomeDirectory + "\"";
    string cmd = "\"" + PgpPath + "\" " + recipient + output + encrypt;

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);
    p.StandardInput.Flush();
    p.StandardInput.Close();
    processExited = p.WaitForExit(3500);
    p.Close();
}
return processExited;
```

}

Im not able to find anything using the Problem signature. Please help

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is `HomeDirectory` and are you running the service as a user, as the system user, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a user context problem.  Probably the user account the services is running under doesn't have access to the file you are trying to encrypt.

To test this theory, go to the service properties and in the 'Log On' tab enter an account that you know has access to the file.  Preferably the same account/password that you are using to run the C# application

You should also be sure that your code is using a full path to the file to encrypt and not a relative path.

Comment: Hi Mark, You are correct it turns out to be a user context problem. I have installed the GPG is my user account and the local administrator is not able to access that path and the second issue is I have created the GPG key from my useraccount an the service is not able to find that key from the administrator account. I have changed the application user context to my user account and it worked!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use Process, why not just run the gpg.exe instead of cmd.exe?
I just did this for a project and had no trouble doing the following

```
private static void encrypt()
    {
        //have to list full path, adding to PATH had no effect 
        ProcessStartInfo gpg = new ProcessStartInfo(
            @"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPT\GPG\gpg.exe",
            @"--no-options --yes --armor --recipient ""recipient"" --encrypt ""file"""
        );
        Process.Start(gpg);
    }
```

Just pass all the command line arguments as the second parameter.